# Merge two lists into one dict that may contain several values for each key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists

```
system = ['System A', 'System B', 'System C']
instrument = ['Instrument 1', 'Instrument 2', 'Instrument 3', 'Instrument 4']
```

The system items may correspond from one to several instrument items, like this:

```
dict = {'System A':['Instrument 1', 'Instrument 2'], 'System B':['Instrument 3'], 'System C':['Instrument 4']}
```

Notice how 'System A' has one list value that is built upon the first two items from *instrument* list

To illustrate better my problem:
[image: Systems and instruments table]

I tried a dict comprehension + zip() but obviously it didn't work. This is what I tried:

```
system_data_dict = {sys:inst for sys, inst in zip(system, instrument)}
```

**Please note that this isn't a CSV problem. The data that I'm aquiring is from a SQL Database and I need to parse it**

I'm banging my head to the keyboard right now lol.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** the system list has been parsed with set()

Comment: How does the grouping work? Why did `System A` take both `Instrument 1` and `Instrument 2` from the second list, what stopped `System B` from taking `Instrument 2` and `Instrument 3`  instead? what is the logic here?

Comment: Precisely. There is no assignment given. How is the program to know?

Comment: @Chase this is data stored in a database, and I'm getting it row by row. I made a mistake in not clarifying that the first list is a set() of the data aquired. I'll edit it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not have multidicts, so you have two options:

1. use multidicts from an existing library e.g. [werkzeug's `MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), when initialised with lists of pairs, will associate multiple values to keys which are present multiple times (unlike dict which will only keep the last value)

   ```py
   system_data_dict = werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict(zip(system, instrument))
   system_data_dict.getlist('System A') # => ['Instrument 1', 'Instrument 2']
   ```
2. alternatively, do that by hand by using a regular loop, even if it's feasible using a comprehension (which I'm not sure about) it's going to look dreadful: use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or the [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method to define a dict mapping keys to *lists* and append values every time

   ```py
   system_data_dict = {}
   for k, v in zip(system, instrument):
      system_data_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
   system_data_dict['System A'] # => ['Instrument 1', 'Instrument 2']
   ```

Comment: This solved my question! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Give a grouping info to your list.

Assuming you are getting items from a database,

```
SELECT System, instrument FROM <src> WHERE System IN ("System A", "System B", "System C")
```

and parsing it to form a list like:

```
items = [("System A", "Instrument 1"), ("System A", "Instrument 2"), ("System B", "Instrument 3"), ...]
```

then use your dictionary code:

```
# system_data_dict = {sys:inst for sys, inst in items}

# EDIT
system_data_dict = {}
for sys, inst in items:
    if sys in system_data_dict.keys():
        system_data_dict[sys].append(inst)
    else:
        system_data_dict[sys] = [inst]
```

Comment: Doesn't work, if a key is present multiple times in the input then only the last associated value will be in the final dict.

Comment: The items list works as expected, but when I try to convert it to a dict, only the last (key, value) is stored.
I tried also this: system_data_dict = {sys:[inst] for sys, inst in items} but it's the same result

Comment: @Masklinn Sorry. Wasn't thinking straight. Made an edit so the value is a list now.